# shell_exec - Permission denied; when executing inside Linux User's Home folder

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

How to allow `shell_exec` to read the text file that is inside another user's home directory?

**The idea I want to achieve:** display content of a .log file that is inside `Home` folder of a Linux user named `steam`.

I have a `server_log.php` file inside `/var/www/html/`. It tries to read and **echo** the `.log` text file that is deep inside `/home/steam/` directory.

**server_log.php**

```
<?php echo shell_exec("cat /home/steam/.local/share/Steam/steamcmd/7dtd/7DaysToDieServer_Data/output_log__2024-02-13__08-54-45.txt"); ?>
```

And it does not work, after longer investigation and opening the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` this is the error that is seen:

```
cat: /home/steam/.local/share/Steam/steamcmd/7dtd/7DaysToDieServer_Data/output_log__2024-02-13__08-54-45.txt: Permission denied
```

Now the next logical step was to try to find every way to give read permission to the `www-data` user that is responsible for executing everything inside `shell_exec`. Nothing worked so far and I've read countless threads on setting the Linux permissions.

Any information that could help to understand or solve the problem is appreciated.

Comment: What permissions does the folder actually have?

Comment: Never shell_exec() when you can just readfile().

Comment: As of right now the default ones; as I mentioned I've tried to apply all permissions and groups to most related files and folders and all the effort did not lead anywhere.

Comment: If you _really_ "tried it all", there'd be no help, and this question would be useless. If you expect this question to be useful, you obviously haven't tried all possible options: Please be more specific and provide as much information as possible by editing it into your question - e.g. full permissions for the file, folder (-hierarchy), and what you tried with which exact result. Check [mcve]

Comment: I've provided the minimal reproducible example and the error. I never mentioned that I've "tried it all". I've mentioned that all my efforts gave no result. The question is solid and includes all the necessary content to give an answer.